# Inject services recursively in Laravel

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, out-of-memory

I am using Laravel 5.2.45.
I am using dependency injection for my services.
Now, there is `service A` that needs `service B`, so I inject `service B` into `A`.
Also, there are methods in `service B`, that need `service A`, so I also injected `service A` into `B`.
However, this configuration seems to create a problem. This is my implementation:

```
class AService
{
  /**
   * @var BService
   */
  protected $bService;

  public function __construct(BService $bService) {
    $this->bService = $bService;
  }
}

class BService
{
  /**
   * @var AService
   */
  protected $aService;

  public function __construct(AService $aService) {
    $this->aService = $aService;
  }
}
```

First I noticed that my routes are not working, so I tried checking them with:

```
php artisan route:list
```

And I got:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in
>   /var/www/tacnet-plus/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 1426
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

It seems that this configuration creates a memory overflow. I suspect that the first service creates the second and the second creates the first indefinitely. 
I have had the same issue in the past with Java Spring, and I know you can inject your services there with a setter instead of the constructor, to avoid creating the dependency in the constructor and inject the service on demand through the setter. ***Is there something similar in Laravel?***

Comment: Have you tried registering the services as a singleton? I'm not sure if this will work, but I understand the loop you are creating now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is nothing out of the box that will inject a service without using the constructor. However, I can change one of both services to inject the other service manually in a getter, instead of the constructor:

```
class AService
{
  /**
   * @var BService
   */
  protected $bService;

  public function __construct(BService $bService) {
    $this->bService = $bService;
  }
}

use App;
class BService
{
  public function __construct() {
  }

  /**
   * @return AService
   */
  private function getAService() {
    return App::make('Some\Namespace\AService');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to use \App::make('Some\Namespace\AService'); instead of App::make('Some\Namespace\AService'); see https://github.com/skovmand/mailchimp-laravel/issues/10

Comment: No this is not a problem, I have an import for this: use App;